# MS Enterprise Library Data Block to pass XML into the a stored procedure with a XML parameter

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, enterprise-library

In my apps I typically use the Enterprise Library Data Block to simplify my database interactions.  C# code such as:

```
public static IDataReader AdminNavigation_Insert(int iGroupId, string sText, string sRelativeUrl, int iSortOrder)
{ 
  return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("database").ExecuteReader(
        "cms_uspAdminNavigation_Insert", 
        iGroupId, 
        sText, 
        sRelativeUrl, 
        iSortOrder);
}
```

would insert into a stored procedure like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cms_uspAdminNavigation_Insert]
    @GroupId int,
    @Text nvarchar(500) = NULL,
    @RelativeUrl varchar(100) = NULL,
    @SortOrder int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.cms_tblAdminNavigation (
    GroupId, Text, RelativeUrl, SortOrder, TsCreated, TsUpdated
) VALUES (
    @GroupId, @Text, @RelativeUrl, @SortOrder, getDate(), getDate()
);
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
END
```

Now, if one of those stored procedure parameters were xml, what C# datatype would I use to pass to that stored procedure via the Enterprise Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String = SQLDbBtype.xml

See [C#/SQL - What’s wrong with SqlDbType.Xml in procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574928/c-sql-whats-wrong-with-sqldbtype-xml-in-procedures)

[Or another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698153/calling-a-stored-procedure-using-c-with-xml-datatype)

Edit, however for [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx#TextMapping) it may be System.Xml.Linq.XElement