# passing xml data into a string to be used as a parameter

Tags: c#, xml

Having trouble dealing with xml and to properly use it for my purpose. So i am creating a test method and one of the parameters is xml data and i am not sure how to pass it in.

**Service**

```
public IEnumerable<Submissions> CheckingOutForUserReview(string data)
        {
            var _submissions = DataContextManager.StoredProcs.CheckingOutForUserReview<SSubmissions>(data, s => new Submissions
            {
               QRCodeGUID = SubmissionsColumnMap.QRCodeGUID(s),
               StoragePath = SubmissionsColumnMap.StoragePath(s),
               UploadedByUsersID = SubmissionsColumnMap.UploadedByUsersID(s)
            });

            return _submissions;
        }
```

**Stored Proc:**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> CheckingOutForUserReview<T>(string data, Func<IDataRecord, T> modelBinder)
        {
            SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("dbo.CheckingOutForUserReview");
            _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "Data", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml, Value = data });
            return DbInstance.ExecuteAs<T>(_command, modelBinder);
        }
```

This is my TestMethod:

```
    public void CheckingOutForUserReview()
            {
string _data = @"<CheckingOutForUserReview xmlns:i=""www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""schemas.name.com/2013/03/Malt.Models"">
                                <Record>
                                <QRCodeID>2FAC636E-F96C-4465-9272-760BAF73C0DF</QRCodeID>
                                <SubmissionID>10B5236C-47FD-468D-B88D-D789CA0C663A</SubmissionID>
                                <UserID>1</UserID>
                                <Page>1</Page>
                                </Record>
                            </CheckingOutForUserReview>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(_data);
            var _Svc = new SubmissionsService();
            var _checkins = _Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(doc.InnerXml);
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
my CheckingOutForUserReview() method accepts a XmlDocument as i changed it to that in my stored procedure and with what i currently have it is giving an error that i have invalid arguments(System.Xml.XmlDocument) not sure if i messed up somewhere.

If this is a different way i am also open in trying new ways. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't you just save the XML to a separate file and then load it from there? Also, your XML is not valid, you open `<Record>` once, but then close it twice.

Comment: @svick so there isn't a way to do it in the test method itself? i just want to test and make sure i am returning what i need. Thanks for catching the markup for closing record.

Comment: Is there some reason your using a string and not an XElement for dealing with the xml itself ?

Comment: @johnv2020 no there is no reason other than i don't know what is the best way going about this. First time dealing with xml this way.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you want to do with the xml its difficult to say - but in general you should definetely use an xml type, XElement or XDocument when dealing with xml data and not simple strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see there are two ways:

1. You should save your xml into an xml file by adding xml file in your
   project then use it with XmlDocument using *Load* method like:

   ```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument.Load(FileName);
   ...
   ...
   var _checkins = _Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(doc.innerXml);
   ```
2. Save your xml as a string literal and use it with XmlDocument using
   *LoadXml* method like:

   ```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument.LoadXml(stringThatContainsXml);
   ...
   ...
   var _checkins = _Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(doc.innerXml);
   ```

You can use *XDocument* and *XElement* classes as well but my focus on *XmlDocument* is that it will work for framework less than 3.5 too since `XDocument` and `XElement` is introduced in framework 3.5.

Also loading xml into a parser will help to filter out the invalid xml. (if mistakenly tried to use)

Another thing i have noticed in your snippet:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(_data);
```

It should come before the initialization of `_Svc`, because if there is no data in `_data` initialization doesn't make sense.

So your code looks like:

```
public void CheckingOutForUserReview()
{
    string _data = "I want to pass in xml here";

    Assert.IsNotNull(_data);  <--------------- See the re-ordering

    var _Svc = new SubmissionsService();
    var _checkins = _Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(_data);
}
```

Comment: I really don't see a reason to be compatible with something which was released 6 years ago and which has been surpassed by 4.0 since 3 years.. IMO it should rather be a preference of how you write your code.

Comment: @Default, if something is supported in All frameworks I would prefer it and definitely it matters how the code is written(say implemented by LINQ). Truly it is only my opinion.

Comment: @NeverHopeless thank you for all the information you have shared. I tried making changes (updates above) but i am running into errors because i changed the parameter for xml from `string data` to `XmlDocument data` type and not sure how to set the xml as a parameter in the stored procedure.

Comment: Change : `var _checkins = _Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(doc.LoadXml(_data));` to `doc.LoadXml(_data); var _checkins = _Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(doc.innerXml);`

Comment: Why would you `XmlDocument` if you're going to pass the XML as a `string` anyway? Just `_Svc.CheckingOutForUserReview(stringThatContainsXml)` is much simpler.

Comment: @svick, What if the xml is invalid ? It will help to parse and acknowledge before the service gets something wrong..

Comment: @NeverHopeless That's the job of the service to verify that. There is no reason to unit test the unit test.

Comment: @svick, It depends how things are handled, without looking at the service inside, we can not predict if it is handled in service or not so it would be good if it is mentioned at this point (as i did earlier in my post). I think OP passes this string directly to the stored procedure.

Comment: I added the service method i have above

Comment: These are custom classes we might need to look more code (if necessary) but first i have to know is your error message disappeared ?

Comment: yes it disappeared but when i debug my test method it says the @Data was not supplied.

Comment: @NeverHopeless i also added what i had in stroed procs

Comment: Can you please verify the parameter name's case is correct.. Also, put a break point and check `_data` is passing correctly. For more info on passing xml to sproc's XML type look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698153/calling-a-stored-procedure-with-xml-datatype

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in a comment, I think the best way to do this is to save the XML into a separate file.

If you don't want to do that, you can use verbatim string literal (note the double quotes):

```
string data = @"<CheckingOutForUserReview xmlns:i=""www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""schemas.name.com/2013/03/Malt.Models"">
    <Record>
    <QRCodeID>2FAC636E-F96C-4465-9272-760BAF73C0DF</QRCodeID>
    <SubmissionID>10B5236C-47FD-468D-B88D-D789CA0C663A</SubmissionID>
    <UserID>1</UserID>
    <Page>1</Page>
    </Record>
</CheckingOutForUserReview>";
```

Comment: Learn something every day, didn't know you could use `""` instead of `\"`.

Comment: @Bob. Well, not exactly, you can either use normal string literal and `\"`, e.g. `"\""`, or you can use verbatim string literal and `""`, e.g. `@""""`.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what do you think is wrong with this answer? I think it does exactly what the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what is the problem in passing any kind of strings as a parameter into a method

If your XML is generated from your code, you better have used a StringBuilder to build it to reduce creating new references while concatenating your string.

If your XML is originally from a file, pass the file path into your method, and open the document there. there are a lot of different ways to open and read XML documents, or loading a string to an XML document and deal with it as XML rather than a string.

Examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24375/Working-with-XML

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58239-c-tutorial-reading-and-writing-xml-files/

and finally from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288481%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

enjoy

Comment: If your XML is generated from your code, you better use a XML library (e.g. LINQ to XML), **not** `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @svick, voting down for wrong answers, or not related answers, not if you think there is a better way of a posted answer

Comment: I think voting down is also for answers that are technically correct, but are bad practice. And I think your answer fits that.

Comment: well, then all answers except the accepted one should be voted down in that case, and that means also the question itself should be voted down, because the poster is using a string already, and there is a better way to deal with XML

Comment: BTW, the question is edited, it was only the last code part, maybe that's why you think my answer is off the correct way to answer the question, but it wasn't, i mentioned the stringbuilder because of that